# How to test the increase of proportions

Tags: r, proportion

Let say I've a contigency table as :

```
           score
           <=2  [3-4]  >=5
no_event   248    796  288
event       71    419  285
```

I computed the percentage of events for each score category (`<=2`, `[3-4]` and `>=5`). Hereby the plot (top of each bar displays the number of `events / (events+no_event)` .

[image]

I would like to test if the increase in proportion between `>2` -> `[3-4]` -> `>=5` is significative.

My first idea would be to use a chisq or fisher exact test.

```
 m <- matrix(c(248,71,796,419,288,285),ncol=3)
 fisher.test(m)$p.value
 [1] 9.640235e-17
```

However this test didn't take into account the order of the categories  `>2` -> `[3-4]` -> `>=5`

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One is to use a [Cochran Armitage trend test](https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2007/sp/SP05.pdf). There is an implementation in R. I suppose you are interested in event vs non-event, so you need to flip your matrix:

```
library(DescTools)
m <- matrix(c(71,248,419,796,285,288),ncol=3)
CochranArmitageTest(m)

Cochran-Armitage test for trend

data:  m
Z = 8.5195, dim = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Since you have two groups, and you know the average score in event is higher, you can also test the difference of the scores using a wilcoxon:

```
event_scores =  rep(1:3,m[1,])
noevent_scores =  rep(1:3,m[2,])

wilcox.test(event_scores,noevent_scores)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  event_scores and noevent_scores
W = 618058, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```