# Counter-intuitive result from Cochran Armitage trend test and glm binomial

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, proportion, trend, cochran-armitage

My question is motivated by the Q&A at [How to test the increase of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485977/how-to-test-the-increase-of-proportions).

The question is how to test for a trend in proportion between events and non-events given an ordinal risk of 3 categories.

One answer there suggests using Cochran Armitage test, my suggestion would be using a glm with family distribution binomial. Either way, I find the results counterintuitive since they strongly suggest a trend when, in my opinion, the evidence is quite weak given that effectively
there are only 3 datapoints (i.e. 3 risks categories).

Here's the data:

```
event <- c(71, 419, 285)
not_event <- c(248, 796, 288)
risk <- c(1,2,3)

barplot(event/(event + not_event), xlab= 'Risk', ylab= '% of events')
```

[image]

Results from Cochran Armitage test and glm support a trend with tiny p-values against no-trend hypothesis:

```
library(DescTools)

CochranArmitageTest(rbind(event, not_event))

Z = 8.5195, dim = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

---

```
fit <- glm(cbind(event, not_event) ~ risk, family= binomial())
summary(fit)

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.8842     0.1686  -11.17   <2e-16 ***
risk          0.6233     0.0742    8.40   <2e-16 ***
```

Even more puzzling to me is that bumping up the first risk category still results in a pretty convincing evidence against the null:

```
event <- c(190, 419, 285)
barplot(event/(event + not_event), xlab= 'Risk', ylab= '% of events')
```

[image]

```
CochranArmitageTest(rbind(event, not_event))

Z = 2.627, dim = 3, p-value = 0.008614  <----
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

---

```
fit <- glm(cbind(event, not_event) ~ risk, family= binomial())
summary(fit)

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.7498     0.1411  -5.314 1.07e-07 ***
risk          0.1698     0.0647   2.624  0.00869 **
```

Clearly my understanding and/or my intuition are wrong. How can you claim a trend so convincingly with just three categories going up and down?!